# Building functional logs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Good Afternoon,

So I recently have been shifting my focus to developing more enterprise grade PowerShell scripts and using them across multiple domains and as such issues will happen no matter how many fringe cases you try to imagine and plan for. As such to aid in the troubleshooting of the inevitable problems you need to build logging into the scripts. I have been struggling back and forth of what is the best way to actually build multi-level logging functionality without the script being basically one giant blob of write-this, write-that etc. I am trying to strike a balance between code quantity, code readability, and just amount of development time it takes to tackle the problem.

TLDR; Implementing good logging is hard.

- What decision process do you follow when deciding what to log and what level it should be?
- What are some tips or lessons learned when building more complex tools?

What I have currently settled on (or more like what am I teetering between). I also use `$ErrorActionPreference = Stop` and a trap function to pretty up the errors.

Method 1

```
Write-Debug "Attempting to load BdeHdCfg."
Try { $lMSG = 'Loading BDEHDCFG state: {0}'
    Set-Variable -Name:'BdeHdCfg' -Value:(Start-BdeHdCfg)
    Write-Information ($lMSG -f 'Success')
} Catch {
    Write-Error ($lMSG -f 'Failure')
}
```

Method 2

```
Write-Debug "Attempting to load TPM information."
Try { $lMSG = 'Successfully loaded TPM information: {0}'
    Set-Variable -Name:'TPM' -Value:(Get-TargetTPM)
} Finally {
    Write-Information ($lMSG -f ( -Not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($TPM)))
}
```

Comment: I like your question but it does not really fit StackOverflow guidelines since it will likely result in opinion-based answers rather than some specific issue (See : [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . Check out [psframework](https://psframework.org/documentation/quickstart/psframework/logging.html) though, you might like it. It does the heavy lifting for you. Plus, the author (Friedrich Winmann) made a couple of talks about the framework. Here's [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uy5Qd9g25Dg)

Comment: His module does a lot of the heavy lifting, make it so that it work asynchronously and allo w you to use embedded providers (eg: Log file, event log, SQL, Graylog, Splunk, Azure Log Analytics) and allow you to add your own providers with little effort. Not only that but you can target multiple logs (for instance locally and in Azure log analytics) if you need that kind of scenarios.

Comment: @SagePourpre Yeah... was kind of hoping the mods would take a more lenient view on it as I feel it has actual value to the PowerShell community and there really isn't a good place to ask the question (that I know of). I have looked at PSFrameWork but is isn't particularly great for enterprise environments as its nearly impossible to deploy PowerShell modules in secure environments because of either technical or policy limitations (most often both) so looking for a more native solution.

Comment: Also, PSFramework doesn't really provide the answer to what I am looking for. I am more curious about understanding how people make the determination of what should be log enabled and how to log enable it. Using try/catch functions, testing the value after the fact, etc. What is the more tried and tested method more senior developers have decided on.

Comment: I would say the question is ok on StackOverflow because it `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for enterprise grade PowerShell logging is to use code written and maintained by those who know powershell better than we do.

My de facto method for logging is to use the aptly named `Logging` [module](https://github.com/EsOsO/Logging/), they have great [documentation](https://logging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

It is an actively maintained and mature solution for logging and below is a very basic excerpt for implementing it in your own scripts.

```
Set-LoggingDefaultLevel -Level 'WARNING'
Add-LoggingTarget -Name Console
Add-LoggingTarget -Name File -Configuration @{Path = 'C:\Temp\example_%{+%Y%m%d}.log'}

Write-Log -Level 'INFO' -Message 'Some really useful logging message'
```

Comment: I feel like my question was worded in such a way it was taken as looking for the technical solution to logging and less about the practice of logging.

Comment: Read the source code of the logging module i mentioned then